# ¿como poner a mayusculas la primera y la ultima de cada palabra en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Escribe una función que recibiendo una frase por parámetro devuelva esa misma frase, pero
con la primera y última letra de cada palabra en mayúscula.

Comment: Hola! para que alguien te intente ayudar se espera que hayas dedicado tiempo a intentar resolver tu el problema y luego expliques con las dificultades que te has encontrado  al hacer la pregunta. Puedes ver más consejos aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: genial pablo soy nuevo aca y bueno no sabia como era la tematica. pero ya se para la proxima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function firstAndLastUpperCase(word){ return word.split("").map(function(char,index){
if(index === 0 || index === word.split("").length-1)
return char.toUpperCase();
return char;
}).join("");}

Answer (score 1):

Aquí la tienes, devuelve "PrimerA Y ÚltimA LetrA DE CadA PalabrA EN MayúsculA":

```
function strWordsToCapsFirstLast(frase) {

    let strin = frase.toLowerCase().split("").join("").split(" ");
    for(let i = 0 ; i < strin.length ; i++){
        let len = strin[i].length-1;
        if (len > 0){
            strin[i] = strin[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +strin[i].substring(1, len) + strin[i].substr(len).toUpperCase();
        }else {
            strin[i] = strin[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    return strin.join(" ");
}

let specialcaps = strWordsToCapsFirstLast("primera y última letra de cada palabra en mayúscula");
alert(specialcaps);
```

Comment: Genial Muchas gracias